# dpkg error : debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, aptitude

I get the error processing package error when I `apt upgrade`:

I’ve tried the common solutions mentioned online. But it is stuck in a loop.

```
❯ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.7 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not installed
                    Depends: apparmor (>= 2.10) but it is not installed
                    Depends: mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not installed
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~) but it is not installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.7 (= 5.7.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not installed
                    Recommends: libhtml-template-perl but it is not installed
 phpmyadmin : Depends: libapache2-mod-php or
                       libapache2-mod-phpfilter but it is not installable or
                       php-cgi or
                       php-fpm or
                       php
              Depends: php-mysql but it is not installed or
                       php-mysqli or
                       php-mysqlnd
              Depends: php-json
              Depends: php-common but it is not installed
              Depends: libjs-sphinxdoc (>= 1.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: dbconfig-mysql but it is not installed or
                       dbconfig-no-thanks but it is not installed or
                       dbconfig-common (< 2.0.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: php-gettext
              Depends: php-mbstring
              Depends: php-phpseclib (>= 2.0)
              Recommends: php-gd
              Recommends: mysql-client but it is not installed or
                          mariadb-client but it is not installed or
                          virtual-mysql-client
              Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then I tried:

```
❯ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apparmor dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.0
  libapparmor-perl libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 php-common
  php-gettext php-mbstring php-mysql php-pear php-phpseclib php-xml php7.0-cli
  php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
  php7.0-xml
Suggested packages:
  apparmor-profiles apparmor-profiles-extra apparmor-docs apparmor-utils mysql-server
  | mariadb-server mailx tinyca php-libsodium php-mcrypt php-gmp
Recommended packages:
  libhtml-template-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apparmor dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.0
  libapparmor-perl libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.7 php-common php-gettext
  php-mbstring php-mysql php-pear php-phpseclib php-xml php7.0-cli php7.0-common
  php7.0-json php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline php7.0-xml
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server-5.7
1 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
14 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 20.7 MB/23.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 131 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
...
Selecting previously unselected package php-phpseclib.
Preparing to unpack .../php-phpseclib_2.0.1-1build1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-phpseclib (2.0.1-1build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then:

```
❯ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.29) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up tzdata (2021a-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package tzdata (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up samba-common (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.32) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package samba-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up openssh-server (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on samba-common (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.32); however:
  Package samba-common is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on tzdata; however:
  Package tzdata is not configured yet.
  ...
dpkg: error processing package python-pip-whl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nodejs:
 nodejs depends on ca-certificates; however:
  Package ca-certificates is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package nodejs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 tzdata
 samba-common
 openssh-server
 samba
 ubuntu-minimal
 samba-common-bin
 ca-certificates
 python-pip
 software-properties-common
 python-pip-whl
 nodejs
```

I tried removing the package listed here with

```
❯ sudo apt-get remove $pkg -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libapache2-mod-php7.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php-pear' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-cli' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-gd' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-json' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-mysql' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-opcache' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-readline' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-xml' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-mbstring' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.0-mcrypt' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-gfxpayload-lists : Depends: grub-pc (>= 1.99~20101210-1ubuntu2)
 libtcl8.6 : Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
 phpmyadmin : Depends: libapache2-mod-php or
                       libapache2-mod-phpfilter but it is not installable or
                       php-cgi or
                       php-fpm or
                       php
              Depends: php-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                       php-mysqli or
                       php-mysqlnd
              Depends: php-json
              Depends: php-common but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libjs-sphinxdoc (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: dbconfig-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                       dbconfig-no-thanks but it is not going to be installed or
                       dbconfig-common (< 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php-gettext
              Depends: php-mbstring
              Depends: php-phpseclib (>= 2.0)
              Recommends: php-gd
              Recommends: mysql-client but it is not going to be installed or
                          mariadb-client but it is not going to be installed or
                          virtual-mysql-client
              Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not going to be installed
 python3-requests : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 rubygems-integration : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 ssh-import-id : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: openssh-server
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This takes us back to install step. How can I fix this and upgrade all with `apt-get`?

---

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS x86_64

Shell: fish 3.1.2

Answer (score 2):

Your `…is locked by another process…` are most likely caused by another running `dpkg` process. This could be left behind from a previous failed package configuration run.

If you're sure you're not running `dpkg` or `apt` etc in another window, have a look at existing `dpkg` processes and consider `kill`ing them.

```
$ ps awux | grep dpkg
```

As for the other errors, it's all caused by one or more packages failing to configure upon install. Without seeing the logs of that actually happening it's impossible to work out why.

If you're sure you don't need those packages you can remove them until the problem goes away. If even removing the package fails due to problems in pre- or post-rm scripts, you can find those scripts in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`, for example `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server.postrm`, and delete them. Obviously that is the "nuclear option" and not an advisable thing to do if you want to keep those packages around. Should be okay if you're going to immediately reinstall them though.

I do not recommend the mass removal strategy you are pursuing. It's too easy to remove something vital and completely wreck your install. Try to focus on solving individual package installation problems. The output of apt is good at telling you what depends on what. Follow the dependencies to straighten this out.

To aid in solving future problems, keep logs of installation failures. We are not able to properly help because we can not see why these packages failed to configure in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem. In the end, my boot partition was full to the last byte. Some older updates didn't get deleted properly.
Manually deleted the larger and older files there and rebooted. Worked again

To check your (boot) partition sizes, use a tool like "baobab" https://linux.die.net/man/1/baobab.

!Double check the file names before you delete something there!
You could mess up your system